# OOP issue related to explicit type conversion / subclassing

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

This question is related to the concept of object oriented design.

In the following example code (C#), I have an abstract base class `Feature`, which has two subclasses: `SubFeature1` and `SubFeature2`. In my main program, I want to instantiate each of them by giving the correspondent parameter (name of class as a string) to the unique method `instantiateFeature()`.

When I run this code, I get an error that basically states that the type `OOP_example.Feature` cannot implicitely converted to `OOP_example.SubFeature1` because an explicite conversion is already existing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OOP_example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Organization myOrga = new Organization();

            SubFeature1 subObj1 = myOrga.instantiateFeature("SubFeature1");
            SubFeature2 subObj2 = myOrga.instantiateFeature("SubFeature2");
        }
    }

    public class Organization
    {
        Feature obj;

        public Feature instantiateFeature(string s)
        {
            if (s.Equals("SubFeature1"))
            {
                obj = new SubFeature1();
            }
            else if (s.Equals("SubFeature2"))
            {
                obj = new SubFeature2();
            }

            return obj;
        }
    }

    public abstract class Feature
    {
        public abstract void doSomething();
    }

    public class SubFeature1 : Feature
    {
        private int[] _val1;

        //constructor
        public SubFeature1()
        {
            _val1 = new int[2];
            _val1[0] = 1;
            _val1[1] = 2;            
        }

        //this is the only method that inherits from class Feature
        public override void doSomething()
        {
            //not implemented yet
        }

        //this is some other class that does not inherit from Feature
        public void doSomethingElse()
        {
            //not implemented yet
        }
    }

    public class SubFeature2 : Feature
    {
        private int[] _val1;

        //constructor
        public SubFeature2()
        {
            _val1 = new int[2];
            _val1[0] = 1;
            _val1[1] = 2;
        }

        //this is the only method that inherits from class Feature
        public override void doSomething()
        {
            //not implemented yet
        }

        //this is some other class that does not inherit from Feature
        public void doSomethingElse()
        {
            //not implemented yet
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to instantiate each subclass directly, because there will be a lot of them in the future. I thought I could use the concept of Inheritance to structure my code, because some methodes (here, `doSomething()`) exist in all of my classes.

What is the common way to accomplish this? Can anyone show me a best practice?

Thank you!

Comment: You have unusual [Factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) - you expect the same method to return different types. Normally you should not care from outside the factory if `instantiateFeature` returned `Feature` or any of derived classes... If you need to distinguish - consider separate methods with unique return type. When done playing consider existing DI framework to deal with creation of objects.

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly the point here, of what I don't want. I do not want to have a separate method for each subclass. Is there no way to accomplish this?

Comment: Feels like a bad idea (mainly due to need to cast/loosing strong type) to me to expect different types based on string... Consider if `T instantiate<T>(string)` would work for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of your `instantiateFeature` method is `Feature`, so if you want to assign it to a `SubFeature1`, you need to cast:

```
        SubFeature1 subObj1 = (SubFeature1)myOrga.instantiateFeature("SubFeature1");
        SubFeature2 subObj2 = (SubFeature2)myOrga.instantiateFeature("SubFeature2");
```

But anyway, if you already know the concrete type that the method is going to return, there is no point in using a factory method; you might as well instantiate the concrete class directly. The point of a factory method is usually to abstract the calling code from the actual implementation:

```
        Feature subObj1 = myOrga.instantiateFeature("SubFeature1");
        Feature subObj2 = myOrga.instantiateFeature("SubFeature2");
```

As a side note, in your `Organization` class, you should declare `obj` as a local variable, not a field. Making it a field means that the `instantiateFeature` method is not thread-safe.

Comment: Thank you! Now it all works! It took me some time, because there was an additional error in my WCF application. The reason I want to use factory method is that I am using this in a WCF application. That means, my factory method represents the Operation Contract. Still having one more question, though: What do you mean by thread-safe? Can you provide an example of how to declare `obj`?

Comment: I mean, in my actual application, which is a WCF Service, `instantiateFeature` represents my Operation Contract and class `Operation` represents my Service Contract.

Comment: Do you mean, I should write `Feature obj {get; set;}` instead of `Feature obj;`? I need `obj` to be a class variable, because other methods in my class also have to be able to manipulate/delete it.

Comment: @Boozzz, I mean that `obj` should be declared *in* the `instantiateFeature` method, as a local variable, not as a field (or class variable). By "not thread-safe", I mean that if several threads are calling the method at the same time, you will get unpredictable results, because all the thread will access the same variable, so it's possible to have a scenario like that: 1) Thread 1 sets `obj` to a new instance of `SubFeature1`. 2) Thread 2 sets `obj` to a new instance of `SubFeature2`. 3) Thread 1 returns `obj`, which is a `SubFeature2` when it should have been a `SubFeature1`.

Comment: Hmm, I think that would not be possible. I need it as a field, because otherwise I would have to pass it as a parameter to different methods in class `Organization` via TCP (it is a distributed system), which will make everything too slow. I guess, I could use some synchronization, such as SpinLock or Monitor. However, I am actually not using any Threads. Would I still have to synchronize? Or is there another option?

Comment: If it's a WCF service, how can you be sure there will never be several clients calling it at the same time? Even if you don't explicitly use multiple threads explicitly, any server app that supports multiple clients is intrinsically multithread...

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept you are trying to use is not really inheritance but polymorphism, what you should do is create an object with the type Feature and associate with a new Feature1/2. When you use a method on one of these, it will search the "executive" type first.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Polymorphism seems to be exactly what I am trying to use. I don't really understand your description. Can you possibly give me an example?

Comment: What i suggest is that you keep your inheritance but when you instanciate your object, use Feature as declared type and new SubFeature as the executive type 

    (Feature my_feature = new SubFeature();)

, when a method is called on the object it will seek the method within the executive type (subFeature) If you look for a bit more information about polymorphism maybe it will be better explained ^^

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I am doing, when I assign `obj = new SubFeature1()`?

Comment: In Organisation the code seems right but in your main routine you declare your objects as SubFeatures but not Features. I think you should declare them as Feature. That may be the reason why your compiler is yelling at you.

Comment: My compiler does not complain, when I do casting, as suggested by Thomas Levesque. `SubFeature1 subObj1 = (SubFeature1)myOrga.instantiateFeature("SubFeature1");`

Answer (score 0):

`instantiateFeature` returns `Feature`, which can be either `SubFeature1` or `SubFeature2`. What if you write `SubFeature1 a = myOrga.instantiateFeature("SubFeature2");`? Compiler can't be sure, so it shows you an error. The purpose of such abstract base class is to define some parts which is realy impotant, something enough for you to work without worring which of subclasses you are using right now. So what you do is design such `Feature` base class and write code, which uses only `Feature` variables.

**EDIT, text is too large for comment**

Let me show you a little example of what I'm talking about. Imagine we have subfeatures, one of them orders pizza. Now we have subclasses: OrderPizzaByPhoneFeature, OrderPizzaByEmailFeature. Both of their `doSomething` order pizza, but in a different way. In our application it is a user setting. Now to order pizza we call `instantiateFeature` and pass it "I want to order pizza" or maybe calling `instantiatePizzaFeature`. Inside `instantiateFeature` looks for settings and decides if it need to create OrderPizzaByPhoneFeature or OrderPizzaByEmailFeature. We get `Feature` and call it's `doSomething`, which does exactly what we want to do. Now if we want to add some new order type `OrderPizzaByPigeonMailFeature` all we need to do is to add user setting and few lines in `instantiateFeature`. Ordering code still works fine, it never knew about `Feature` subclasses. Well maybe it knew there is some ordering pizza features, but never knew how many of them exist.

Comment: So, in other words, what you suggest is to create classes `Feature1`, `Feature2`, `Feature3`,... without using inheritance. Then, I wouldn't need `Organization`.

Comment: No, I suggest to handle `instantiateFeature` return value as if it was base class - `Feature`. And design `Feature` in a way that anyone who call `instantiateFeature` doesn't care if returning value `Feature1` or `Feature2`.

Comment: Yes, I guess that sounds like what I have to do. But actually, my question is how to do that...

Comment: If obj type is `Feature`, then it is the same, but only because of `instantiateFeature` implementation takes string with concrete subclass name as parameter. If it'd implemented the way it could decide which subclass to create by itself or by using more complex parameters, there would be an advantage in using it. Like it would be easily to add new subclasses or remove existing.